# Domain only for web server

Tags: dns, firewall, apache-httpd

I have a domain which I want to point to my server.

But I don't want to allow other people to use this domain to reach the server, only specific ports on the server (web server, so port 80).

So if someone want to reach the server on my domain on port x then don't let it, but if the port is y then let.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Is it for Apache or Nginx?

Comment: @JohannesM Oh yeah, sorry. It's Apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not, with one IP address. The server is not being addressed by name, only by address. It doesn't matter which hostname resolves to the address, the same connection will happen. The port also is not used in name resolution, so you cannot affect that in any way.

The only practical way would be to put the names to point to different IPs, all of which are used on that server. This will look like only certain ports are accepted, but of course the user can change the hostname or access the server via the other IP directly.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare in proxy mode would help with this, as it will hide the server IP and will only allow traffic on port 80 and 443. If you wanted to make the server accessible through the domain on other ports, then another approach must be used.